# Integration involving substitution, integration by part and partial fraction

Tags: integration, partial-fractions, substitution, integration-by-parts

I am trying to design an integration question which involves three methods, namely substitution, integration by part and partial fraction.

However, I couldn't design such a question. The best I can do involves at most $2$ methods, but not $3$. For example,

$$\int x^8 e^{x^3}  \ dx$$

The integral above involves only substitution $(u=x^3)$ and by part, but not partial fraction.

> It would be good if someone can come out a question involving three methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example could be
$$
\int\frac{x^2\ln x}{\left(1+x^3\right)^2}\:dx.
$$
By the change of variable $u=x^3$, $du=3x^2dx$, one gets
$$
\int\frac{x^2\ln x}{\left(1+x^3\right)^2}\:dx=\frac19\int\frac{\ln u}{\left(1+u\right)^2}\:du,
$$ then one may use an integration by parts
$$
\frac19\int\frac{\ln u}{\left(1+u\right)^2}\:du=-\frac{\ln u}{9\left(1+u\right)}+\frac19\int\frac1{u\left(1+u\right)}\:du
$$and conclude by partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Nice; I also ended up looking at an example where the second step was integrating $\frac{\ln u}{(u + 1)^2}$. The point here is to reverse-engineer from the requirement that the integral you get after integration by parts is a rational function.

Comment: Really a nice question. Even I integrate using by part first ($u = \ln(x)$ and $v^{\prime} = \frac{x^2}{(1+x^3)^2})$, I still have to use partial fraction after that.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int\left(xe^{x^2}+x\log x+{1\over x^2-1}\right)\,dx$$

Comment: This is sort of cheating; you're asking three questions disguised as one question.

Comment: I've gotten where I am today by cheating – I don't see any reason to stop now.

Comment: To me this answer is not cheating. It reflects the complexity of really identifying how integration works. (+1)